# ERB in HTML background syntax highlighting with Sublime Text 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

So I was following a Railscast and I noticed that inside of the `html.erb` file the `ruby` code has a faint background highlight effect to differentiate it from the rest of the HTML document.

I realize Ryan uses TextMate. I am using Sublime Text 3. How can I achieve the same effect? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: what color scheme are you using @Fab ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the ERB package for Sublime Text.

Assuming you have the Sublime Text package manager installed*, just hit `cmd+shift+P` to get the command menu, than type `install package` and select

> Package Control: Install Package

to get the package manager menu.

In that menu, type `ERB` and select the package when you see it. That's it!

*[Here's how to install the package manager](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation).

NB: Once installed, you'll need to make sure HTML (Rails) mode is set.

[image]

And here's what the coloring should look like (with Sublime Text's Twilight color scheme):

[image]

Comment: So I installed ERB but nothing changed? Setting perhaps?

Comment: Just curious does this work for you? and are you on Linux, Mac, or Windows?

Comment: The one word that saved the day! `Twilight` -> That did it! I was using `Monokai` -- `Twilight` is pretty too. Love it. You sir deserve an awesome-o badge. Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44993/discussion-between-feed-me-code-and-jmromer)